# Python fromkeys not working

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

So I want to copy all keys from one dictionary into another, and initialize it with an empty list:

```
filtered_result = {}
for key in result.keys():
    filtered_result[key] = []
```

So I tried a more elegant way to do the same:

```
filtered_result = {}
filtered_result.fromkeys(result.keys(), [])
```

But the second way doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `filtered_result = dict.fromkeys(result.keys(), [])`

Comment: @Alik: no, because that'll **reuse** the same list object for all values. Perroloco, the correct expression is `filtered_result = {k: [] for k in result}`. Note that there is *no need to call `dict.keys()` here*, iterate directly over the dictionary and save yourself a method call and creation of another object where none is needed.

Comment: @Perroloco: you didn't specify *in what way* it doesn't work. You'll increase your chances of getting a good answer if you do (and maybe even provide an example).